# How to add validation message for required controls

Tags: html, .net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC form with few controls as required. I have added required attribute in `th` element. It is not going to next page if there is no data for the control but I am unable to add validation message "Please provide data for required field".

How can I add that?

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
     @Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.StudentName, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
</div>
```

**UI**

[image]

Comment: Have you add a data annotation `[Required]`  on the model ?

Comment: No. That is a dynamic data that comes from backend

Comment: How about put it(@Html.TextAreaFor) into the form ? it will show:https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvBvj.png

Answer (score 1):

HTML does it like this.

```html
<form>
  <label for="choose">Write something</label>
  <input type=text required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```